# Input type file bootstrap class styling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, view, asp.net-mvc-5, input-type-file

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and I have a View where the user can upload a file.

Here is my code:

```
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Asset", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" class="btn btn-default" name="image" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="upload" />
    }
</p>
```

The "Choose file" button is the old default style of button.

Can I please have some help to have the bootstrap style of button, instead of the default button style? I am not sure of the correct class to use.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<span class="btn btn-danger btn-file">
    Browse <input type="file">
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-file {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: white;
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
}
```

For more details you go through this [LINK](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/)

Comment: The css given in this answer is from a post that offers it as an option for reproducing the new, modern file input look on legacy browsers and does not answer the original question at all.